# Spring + Hibernate + MS SQL server - UTC time zone

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, datetime, timezone

I have developed simple application with Spring 4.2.5 + Hibernate 5.1.0 - database system is MS SQL Server 2014.

From few days I am struggling with correct storing time + timezone in database.

Requirements that I need to fulfill is:

1. Save all dates in UTC time zone.
2. Store timezone in database column value.

To achieve it I created model called MyComment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_COMMENT")
@EntityListeners(value = { MyCommentListener.class })
@Audited
public class MyComment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DATE_", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp date;

    ...
}
```

To enforce saving dates in UTC time zone I used Jadira framework:

```
    hibProperties.put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", true);
    hibProperties.put("jadira.usertype.javaZone", "UTC");
    hibProperties.put("jadira.usertype.databaseZone", "UTC");
```

However during each create/update operation of MyComment object, MyCommentListener is getting date from my local timezone (not UTC date!):

```
public class MyCommentListener {

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void setLastUpdate(MyComment myComment) {
        myComment.setDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
```

}

Do you know how can I solve this issue?

1. Should I use other date type in my model? Different than Timestamp?
2. What kind of type should be DATE_ column in MS SQL server database?

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: maybe you should add a 'jadira' tag. You should also specify if you want a timezone *name* or *offset* stored in the database column.

Comment: Could you please describe it more? I do not get what you mean exactly.

Comment: The jadira tag because you are using their types. Your requirements seem technical (store UTC) but then 'Store timezone in database column value.' miss to specify if timezone offset or identifier. Identifier has more informations, see https://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/#tzids and https://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/#datetime  It depends on what you need to do. What is the purpose of storing the timezone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very strange for me that there's no property in Spring to set up default TimeZone - at least I do not know about it.

After some googling I found out that the best place in Spring to set time zone is `WebApplicationInitializer`, so I prepared following code:

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        setupTimeZone();
    }

    private void setupTimeZone() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the problem is with listener. Replace the following code in listener and verify. Change the date format as per your need.

```
    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void setLastUpdate(MyComment myComment) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        myComment.setDate(dateFormat.getCalendar().getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. That code will work, but I am looking for a generic solution that would use UTC time zone by default in my Spring application. Let's imagine that I have 10 listeners that are injecting time to my models, then I would need to repeat above code 10 times. 
I expected that since I am  using Jadira, it will use UTC time zone as default time zone.

Comment: if you want to put your entire app into UTC then use it at the time of startup TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timezone property in the application properties file as below.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```